# How do I write an SQL to check if two columns have the same value or not in MySQL 5.5?

Tags: mysql

Columns that need to be checked

[image]

I need to check if the two columns in this table match or if any do not match to export to a txt file

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Please dont treat SO like a code writing service. First try writing some SQL yourself, do some research, and if your SQL is not behaving as you expected and you are unable to figure out why, SO is there to help

Answer (score 2):

Just a simple `SELECT` query with `WHERE` should do, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE idexx_patient_id = external_patient_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will export all rows in which the two columns in your question do not match to a text file

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable where idexx_patient_id <> external_patient_id
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/donotmatchrows.txt'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```